Generic class in C# does not subscribe to a class event
Im building a mario game in c# with unity.
as part of it, im implementing collactibles items (such as coins, axe and lives).
i started with implementing the coin and the axe. the coin works well. i have a coin script thats related to the coin GameObject in the unity editor. i have a coinManager script that inheite from a generic class named CollectablesManager.
here is the coin logic (and the generic collectables class):
CollectableManager.cs:
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine;

public class CollectableManager<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected int count = 0;

    protected virtual void OnEnable()
    {
        //create delegate instance and add the handles to it

        EventInfo eventInfo = typeof(T).GetEvent("OnCollision");
        if (eventInfo != null)
        {
            Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, this, "OnCollect");
            eventInfo.AddEventHandler(this, handler);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnDisable()
    {
        EventInfo eventInfo = typeof(T).GetEvent("OnCollision");
        if (eventInfo != null)
        {
            Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, this, "OnCollect");
            eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(this, handler);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnCollect()
    {
        count++;
        UpdateUI();
    }

    protected virtual void UpdateUI()
    {

    }

}

SC_Coin.cs:
using UnityEngine;

public class SC_Coin : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void CoinCollisionHandler();
    public static event CoinCollisionHandler OnCollision;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            OnCollision();
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

}

SC_CoinManager.cs:
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class SC_CoinsManager : CollectableManager<SC_Coin>
{
    protected override void UpdateUI()
    {
        GameObject.Find("Txt_Coins").GetComponent<TextMeshPro>().text = "X " + count.ToString();
    }
}


with the coin it all works fine.
here is the axe logic:
SC_Axe.cs:
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class SC_Axe : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void AxeCollisionHandler();
    public static event AxeCollisionHandler OnCollision;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            OnCollision();
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

}


SC_AxeManager.cs:
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class SC_AxeManager : CollectableManager<SC_Axe>
{
    protected override void UpdateUI()
    {
        GameObject.Find("Txt_Axes").GetComponent<TextMeshPro>().text = "X " + count.ToString();
    }
}



when i debug to the point where OnCollision() function of SC_Axe is invoked, i can see that it's null. when i do the same in SC_Coin i can see that its not null.
i understand that if an event is null, thats because no one is subscribing to it. the generic class subscribes to SC_Coin event but for some reason, its not subscribing to SC_Axe event.
i tryed to debug to the beggining of CollectableManager to see if its being create with SC_Axe as T. it doesnt seems to happen

Instead of trying to be smart with reflection, have you thought about just using a static instance of some sort? Instead of having a generic manager as a component, why not have a simple class in between that can be accessed by both the collectables and the interface? Using reflection is a code smell in 99% of the time and I would never use it to subscribe to arbitrary static events somewhere.

Also, you tagged this question with solid, likely because you mean the SOLID principle in software engineering. Not only does your code not follow that, the tag is unrelated to said principle and you should remove it from the question.

@MaxPlay I disagree, solid tag fits here, as OP would like to write code accordingly to solid, and asks for help. Besides, his code follows some of solid rules, for example single responisbility, or open closed

@MG look, you think you are disagreeing with me, but actually, you didn't even bother to read my full comment nor the tags description. "Please do not use this tag for the SOLID OOP principles." It has to be removed, no matter if you think that OP followed SOLID or not. And for your disagreement on the topic of SOLID: If your gameplay code contains UI related code, you didn't separate enough, so my point still stands: This is not SOLID.
